# PDE w/ Dira'c delta as boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, dirac-delta

I acknowledge similar questions have been answered, but despite this I still fail to see the solution to my problem.

[image]

Note that a,b, K are constants.

To the above PDE, I have by way of the product method $U(x,y) = X(x) Y(y)$ found an expression for $X$, but I am struggling with the second condition for $Y(y)$, specifically $U(x,b)=Y(b)=K\delta(x-x_{0})$

I have that $$Y(y)=Acosh(\frac{k\pi}{a}x) + Bsinh(\frac{k\pi}{a}x)$$ giving me after the first condition $Y(0)=0$, that $$Y(b)=Bsinh(\frac{k\pi}{a}b)=K\delta(x-x_{0})$$ which is where I fail to see where to proceed (assuming I haven't made some prior mistake).

Comment: But you don't have $Y(b)=K \delta(x-x_{0})$. The LHS of that expression is independent of any coordinates, the RHS is $x$ dependent. The general solution is $$U=\sum_{n \ge 1}A_{n}\sin\left(\frac{n \pi x}{a}\right)\sinh\left(\frac{n \pi y}{a}\right)$$ Applying the final boundary condition gives $$U(x,b)=\sum_{n \ge 1}A_{n}\sin\left(\frac{n \pi x}{a}\right)\sinh\left(\frac{n \pi b}{a}\right)=\sum_{n \ge 1}\tilde{A}_{n}\sin\left(\frac{n \pi x}{a}\right)=K\delta(x-x_{0})$$ Now multiply both sides by $\sin(m \pi x/a)$ and integrate over the domain to determine the coefficients $\tilde{A}_{n}$.